# Eclipse Plugin auto update installation

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, jar, eclipse-plugin

I am new to eclipse plugin world and I happened to create on hello world plugin.
I am able to give it to my friends by telling them to drop the exported jar (that I exported from my project) in the dropin folder, which works well. But I now want to upload that jar to a web location (say on github) and want them to install it using eclipse-> install new software-> add -> archive option (I think  this is how I should let them install for internal usage) . I tried n number of things without success , a simple approach that I tried was to archive local jar from disk through the eclipse-> install new software-> add -> archive-> local option, but I get error "no software site found at jar:file:/{location to my jar folder}/hello-world_1.0.0.0.2015XXXX.jar!/. Do you wish to edit the location?" message .
  Any guidance is appreciated.

My [plugin.xml](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4QzEqGH9)

My jar folder structure: META-INF,icons,lib,plugin.xml,hello
Testing on same eclipse were-in the dropin method works.

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseP2Update/article.html

Answer (score 2):

To be able to install and update you first need to create a Feature project as well that links to your plug-in. Then at first you should use **Export...** > **Deployable Feature**, select your feature and set **Generate p2 repository** under **Options**. You can generate to a directory first. This will contain:

```
folder/
    +plugins/
    +features/
    +p2/
    -artifacts.jar
    -content.jar
```

You can use this as a local site to install from, and when you upload it to an online location, as an update site.

Once you are fed up with manual exporting, you will learn about maven, tycho and automatic update site creation and upload ;-)

Comment: Thanks @maarten for your quick reply. Can you point me to a good reference guide for all this stuff you mentioned above.

Comment: Try vogella.com such as http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html